# git merge into master removes files that I'd like to keep

Tags: git

So I've got a master branch that has `important_file`, then I created another branch from `master` and did some work there, in part, I removed the `important file` because it should not be there. Then I would like to merge the new branch (no `important_file`) with my master branch, I do this and the `important_file` file gets removed.

I thought there would have been some conflict, because there are changes on the new branch that I would like to integrate into `master` but I don't want that file to be deleted.

A similar issue happens when I create a branch from `master` then accidentally remove some changes in the files there and then when I merge this branch into master, the changes get removed.

How do I avoid it?

Comment: That's exactly how branching and merging supposed to work. Why should `important_file` not be in the branch? What's the point of removing it?

Answer (score 0):

Git is behaving what it is supposed to be.

For your situation, you can delete the file in a single commit to the other branch. Other commits will be as it is supposed to be. Then instead of merging the `other_branch` into master, you can cherry pick the `other_branch`'s  commits to the master branch without the deletion commit.

Hope you got your answer.